# Is there a way to make a class add multiprocessing shared values?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have created a class where all the functions work and can be put into different processes and edited. All of the functions work except the add value function. This is my class:

```
class data(object):

def __init__(self):
    Manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
    self.lock = multiprocessing.Lock()
    self.changeAmt = 0
    self.jump = multiprocessing.Value(ctypes.c_float, 0.02)
    self.has_best = multiprocessing.Value(ctypes.c_bool, False)
    self.best_list = Manager.list()
    self.command_original = 'start sequence'
    self.command = multiprocessing.Value(ctypes.c_wchar_p, self.command_original)
    self.get_best = multiprocessing.Value(ctypes.c_bool, False)
    self.done = multiprocessing.Value(ctypes.c_bool, False)

def get(self, name, model):
    self.model = model
    if model != 'Array':
        with multiprocessing.Lock():
            exec('self.now = self.'+name)
            return self.now.value 
    if self.model == 'Array':
        exec('self.now = self.'+name)
        return self.now

def edit(self, name, model, changeAmt):
    self.changeAmt = changeAmt
    if model != 'Array':
        with multiprocessing.Lock():
            exec('self.'+name+'.value = self.changeAmt')
    if model == 'Array':
        for i in range(len(changeAmt)):
            exec('self.'+name+'.append(changeAmt[i])')

def addValue(self, name, value):
    self.now = value
    exec('self.'+name+' = self.now')
```

Which can then be used correctly with these lines of code in the main function:

```
ult = data()
p1 = Process(target = try2, args=(ult,))
p1.start()
p2 = Process(target = nextTry, args=(ult,))
p2.start()
p1.join()
p2.join()
```

When I go to use the addValue function in my code, the first process works great and can return the value when the get function is called. However, when I go to call the get function for the second process it fails. One of my ideas on a solution is to use the multiprocessing Queue method and have both processes add the value. Although, I have a feeling even if both functions have added the value it will not change if one of them changes the value. Is what I am trying to accomplish do-able, or should I just try to initialize all of my variables from the start?

Comment: The `exec` statements are not a good idea. Read about `getattr`. Example: replace `exec('self.now = self.'+name)` with `self.now = getattr(self, name)`

Comment: Thank you! you're right that it id more efficient and secure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the only way to do this is to use a multiprocessing dictionary, I have posted the working example of an initializer and creator below.

```
def __init__(self):
        Manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
        self.allDict = Manager.dict()
        self.allDict['status'] = 'nothing'
        self.allDict['done'] = False
        self.allDict['changeAmt'] = 0
        self.allDict['command'] = 'start sequence'
        self.allDict['get_best'] = False
```

then if you wanted to add a regular value:

```
 def addValue(self, name, value):
        self.allDict[name] = value
```

This honestly was probably one of the original reasons for the manager dictionary. Anyways, I hope if anyone needs this information and stumbles across this post it helps.